# AngularJS [$parse:syntax] Setting value in anchor

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to assign a variable inside my scope and assign {{post.id}} as the value, then run a function called editPost that will take the value of $scope.editID and send it as a parameter to a page can then console.log it back to me.  Right now I get an error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.17/$parse/syntax?p0=post.id&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=10&p3=editID%3D%7B%7Bpost.id%7D%7D%3B%20editPost()&p4=post.id%7D%7D%3B%20editPost()
```

Here's my code inside the index file:

```
<div class="postDiv" ng-repeat="post in blog.posts" data-id="{{post.id}}">
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editPost" ng-click="editID={{post.id}}; editPost()">
        <img class="edit" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/68/Pencil.svg">
    </a>
</div>
```

Here's what I have in my app.js file for this function:

```
$scope.editPost = function() {
            console.log("ID: "+$scope.editID);
            $http({
                method  : 'POST',
                url     : 'process/getEdit.php',
                data    : $.param($scope.editID),  // pass in data as strings
                headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
            })
            .success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
};
```

Why am I getting this error and how can it be fixed?  I'm assuming that the issue is in setting editID={{post.id}} but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Change `editID={{post.id}};...` to `editId=post.id;...`. You don't need to give expression syntax in this case.

Comment: Yup figured out right before you commented lol.  Make it an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `editID={{post.id}};...` to `editId=post.id;....`. You don't need to give expression syntax in this case